# How to exclude paths for YcmCompleter GoTo command?

Tags: python, vim, youcompleteme, python-jedi

I am working on a sdk project using python in vim. I have a local dir that contains my development work like ~/Project/{my_project}. I also installs the sdk package for python so ~/.pyenv/versions/3.9.11/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/{my_package} contains the sdk files too which is a relased version.

Whenever I use `:YcmCompleter GoTo` in vim, it will direct me to the sdk path installed in python like `~/.pyenv/versions/3.9.11/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/{my_package}/var.py` instead of `~/Project/{my_project}/var.py`.

Is there any way I can exlucde a path or pattern of the path so YcmCompleter GoTo can only find the function declaration in a specific folder?

Comment: Use the plugin's official support channels.

Comment: what is the official support channel? Can you share the link?

Comment: It's in the `README.md`.